# No sound through headphones despite pavucontrol (debian stretch)

Tags: debian, audio, alsa, pulseaudio

After updating from jessie to stretch this week I found my heaphone jack no longer outputs sound, though my built in speakers work just fine. The puzzling thing is that everything seems to be in order as far as I can tell. Pavucontrol shows output to the headphones device, but I don't hear anything. When I mute or unmute I can hear a pop in the headphones. The device is detected and activated when I plug in or remove headphones.

- System Info: Lenovo Carbon X1, Debian Stretch, Card is HDA Intel PCH.
  [my alsa-info.sh](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=ff07b287f2cf2ad9482da186153b14f36a628dfd)
- What works: Headphone Detection, Pavucontrol, Builtin Speaker, I hear a pop when muting/unmuting.
- I've tried the answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working). I've tried purging and reinstalling alsa and pulse audio.

Setting

```
[Element Speaker]
switch = on
volume = ignore
```

in `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-headphones.conf` is a good idea but does not solve my problem.

Comment: I don't have this problem anymore. Some package update fixed it.